# TypeError: string indices must be integers in Python

Tags: python

I want to get key and value from the Json response i got from the currency conveter API.T am getting an error :"of string indices must be integers".Below is the Python code,the data in Json and the error message.

```
import json
from urllib.request import urlopen
with urlopen ("http://free.currencyconverterapi.com/api/v6/convert?q=ZAR_GBP,ZAR_USD")as response:
    source=response.read()
data= json.loads(source)
data=json.dumps(data,indent=2)
print(data)
value= (data['results']['ZAR_GBP']['val'])
print(value)
```

the Json output is:

```
{
  "query": {
    "count": 2
  },
  "results": {
    "ZAR_GBP": {
      "id": "ZAR_GBP",
      "fr": "ZAR",
      "to": "GBP",
      "val": 0.056698
    },
    "ZAR_USD": {
      "id": "ZAR_USD",
      "val": 0.072289,
      "to": "USD",
      "fr": "ZAR"
    }
  }
}
```

If i want to access the key "val' and its value,this is giving me an error

```
---------------------------------------------------------------------------
TypeError                                 Traceback (most recent call last)
<ipython-input-61-eb4254977d14> in <module>()
      5 data= json.loads(source)
      6 data=json.dumps(data,indent=2)
----> 7 print (data['results']['ZAR_GBP']['val'])
      8 

TypeError: string indices must be integers
```

Answer (score 5):

That's because you're converting the json to a string (with json.dumps) and then trying to access said string via keys, which obviously fails, because it's not a json anymore.

It'll work if you remove the `data=json.dumps(data,indent=2)` line.

Comment: @TeeKimSigaukeMuchini glad to hear that. Make sure to mark this as the answer then!